# getopts does not match the second argument

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm trying to get a script to:

- set a variable with `-q` option
- show help for `-h` option, and
- fail for other options `-*`, but allow positional arguments

Here is the `getopts` snippet I'm using:

```
while getopts qh opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
        q)
            quiet="true"
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "unrecognized option -- ${OPTARG}"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo "unparsed: $*"
```

This seems pretty straightforward. However it only works if I provide a single argument (`a.sh -q` or `a.sh -h` do what's expected).

However, it does not do anything if I provide both arguments, or provide an unrecognized argument as at $2:

```
$ ./a.sh -b
unrecognized option -- b

$ ./a.sh -q -b
unparsed: -b

$ ./a.sh -h -k
this is my help message
unparsed: -k
```

Any ideas why the second argument ($2) is not handled in the getopts loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `shift` command is misplaced.  It should be *outside* of the `while` loop.  Try:

```
while getopts :qh opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
        q)
            quiet="true"
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "unrecognized option -- ${OPTARG}"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

echo "unparsed: $*"
```

#### Examples

If we add the following line to the beginning of the code:

```
usage() { echo "this is my help message"; }
```

Then we can do these tests:

```
$ ./a.sh -q -foo
unrecognized option -- f
$ ./a.sh -q -h
this is my help message
```

Comment: Doesn't help. `./a.sh -q -foo` still doesn't hit `unrecognized option` block. Also `-q -h` doesn't hit `h` block either.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan Both work for me.  See the examples shown in my updated answer.  If you see something different, then please copy-and-paste my exact code to a script and try again.  (If you are using some other code not shown here, then I don't know what's in it and I can't help.)

Comment: Thanks it worked on a second try. What's the reason this works and shifting it one by one inside the loop doesn't?

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan Very good.  When the shifting is done inside the loop, getopts gets confused and loses track of its position.  To give getopts a chance to process all the arguments, we need to wait to do the shifting outside the loop after getopts is finished,